# Internet Explorer 9 - 11 ignoring padding-RIGHT in <a> element

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why the heck is IE (I care for at least versions 10 and up) ignoring only `padding-right` on my `a` element?

### CSS:

```
.button { position:relative; display:inline-block; padding: 6px 50px 6px
 15px; margin:20px 10px 20px 0px; text-decoration:none; font-family: 
'Cormorant', serif; font-size:13px; line-height:24px; font-weight:400; 
color:#000; border: 4px double; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:700; 
text-align:center; transition: all 0.25s; }

.button:before { position:absolute; right:0; top:0; width:30px; 
height:100%; background:#000; content:""; transition: all 0.25s; }

.button:after { position:absolute; right:7px; top:50%; margin-top:-11px; 
font-family:"Flaticon"; content: "\f104"; color:#fff }
```

### HTML

```
<a class="button" href="#">View 
Safari</a>
```

What the button is supposed to look like:

[image]

But in IE:

[image]

However without pseudo elements, there seems to be a "default" right padding in IE:

[image]

I expect older versions of IE (like 8 and below) to pull this kind of retarded BS but not 10 and up!

Has anyone experienced this before because I cannot find a working solution on SO?

Answer (score 0):

Damn I spoke too soon!! Just looked though my stylesheet to see if there was any conflict causing this issue and I found this old IE hack I must have put in years ago - which I never really take notice (or care for) because it's IE related.

So for those of you who ever come across this issue, look for any tacky IE hacks like this one in my case:

```
/* INTERNET EXPLORER 8 */

.button {background-image:none\0/; padding-right: 20px\0/;}
```

Still IE's fault for us having to make these stupid hacks in the first place! So glad it's 2017 (unlike around 2012)